# sort order of unicode characters not covered by the collation

Tags: sql-server, unicode, collation

Suppose I have a stored procedure that declares two Nvarchar variables, and
 those variables happen to hold arabic values.  The default collation of the db
 is Latin1_General_CI_AI, so that is the collation that will be used for the
 comparison.  (per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179886.aspx) .  I know that the collation determines the sort order of the character set, but what does it do, in this case,  for unicode code points that fall outside the Latin range? When I compare the values using greater than/less than,  will it use the proper Arabic sort order?

Hope the question makes sense.